# Error de codigo en Calendario (Python)

Tags: python, tkinter

Soy nuevo en esta pagina, contaré el problema para ver si alguien puede ayudarme.

Hoy estaba haciendo un calendario en Python, con las librerias *tkcalender y tkinter*. Cuando termine el proyecto, lo ejecuté en VSCode, y automaticamente me salio error de repente:

```
"Calendar.__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'select'"
```

Si no llegan a entender el porque de la situacion, aqui esta el codigo entero:

```
from tkinter import *
from calendar import *

root = Tk()
root.title("Calendario GR")
root.geometry("500x350")
root.config(bg="grey")

cal = Calendar(root, select="day", year=2022, mouth=7, day=16)
cal.pack(pady=20, fill="both", expand="yes")

def Fecha():
    Label.config(text="Fecha de hoy: " + cal.get_date())

Button = Button(root, text="fecha", command=Fecha)
Button.pack(pady=20)

Label = Label(root)
Label.pack(pady=20)

root.mainloop()
```

Comencé a programar en Python hace 9 meses y estoy tratando de aprender como hacer distintas aplicaciones para mejorar en el mundo de la programacion.

Si alguien me puede ayudar seria de muy buena ayuda. ¡Muchas gracias!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tu código tiene dos errores:

- Estás importando el modulo incorrecto (es probable que en realidad estés importando el modulo [calendar](https://docs.python.org/es/3/library/calendar.html) de la librería estandar, el cual también tiene una clase Calendar que acepta un solo argumento). Lo que querés importar es el modulo tkcalendar (`from tkcalendar import *`)
- Incluso solucionando ese error, la clase Calendar no acepta ningún argumento llamado `select`. ¿Puede ser que hayas querido usar `selectmode`? Si ese es el objetivo, no es necesaria la parte de `selectmode="day"`, ya que esta es la configuración predeterminada.

Solucionando ambos errores, el código queda así:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkcalendar import *

root = Tk()
root.title("Calendario GR")
root.geometry("500x350")
root.config(bg="grey")

cal = Calendar(root, year=2022, mouth=7, day=16)
cal.pack(pady=20, fill="both", expand="yes")

def Fecha():
    Label.config(text="Fecha de hoy: " + cal.get_date())

Button = Button(root, text="fecha", command=Fecha)
Button.pack(pady=20)

Label = Label(root)
Label.pack(pady=20)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Gracias, realmente yo estuve haciendo un tutorial de Youtube. Me parecia raro que no funcionase el programa. ¡Muchas gracias!

Comment: De nada! Me alegra haber ayudado c: te agradeceria si votas/aceptas mi respuesta en forma de apoyo nwn